# Symfony's console PHP 7 parsing error

Tags: symfony, console, php-7

(Using WampServer on Windows 10.)

In some of my PHP class, I used return type declaration as explained in http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php

Most console commands using [my-symfony-project] ... bin\console return

```
Parse error: syntax error, undexpected ':', expecting ';' or '{' in [file] on line [x]
```

Am I doing something wrong ? Or is there a solution for combining Symfony console **with new PHP 7 features**.

---

Example of function not being parsed by Symfony's console:

```
public function getFamilyName() : string {
    return $this->familyName;
}
```

Comment: I gave enough information about the code in the original question. But I can add some concrete example.

Comment: check if your windows cmd really uses the right php version and not some other one still installed. `php -v`

Comment: @Joe: Good point. CMD uses php 5.6 while I selected PHP 7 in WampServer menu. Do you know how I change that?

Comment: NOt working with windows here but probably you might wanna take a look at your windows PATH variables. There's probably one pointing to the old php executable which you need to edit.

Comment: @Joe: That's right, solved it. You should post it as an answer to I can select it as the answer to the question.

Comment: @TTT sure maybe it helps someone else also :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, undexpected ':', expecting ';' or '{' in [file] on line [x]
```

means normally, that the php version is not correct. 
In your case the Windows command line still runs with an old 5.* Version by default.

This can be fixed by changing the PATH variable pointing to the old php version to the new installed one.